# Unicode characters for database

Tags: php, html, unicode, character

My database for Unicode is successfully working for storing and displaying values. But problem is with the Newline character, tab character and other character. That is it is skipping these character to space. ex. word is

```
I am storing in this way.
दर
बदर

but its showing me output as
दर बदर

If I input
line 1
line 2
Output is "line 1 line 2"
```

1: How this problem will be solved?

2: If I want to store html equivalent for Unicode in database and before displaying again converting to Unicode equivalent. What should I do?

Comment: How are you entering the data and what kind of database are you using? How are you outputting the data? There are a lot of aspects of this problem missing.

Comment: Using this statement
    $hindi=trim($_POST["hindi"]);
Where hindi is name of my textarea.

Comment: HTML/browsers collapse all continuous whitespace into a single space character and ignore line breaks. That's your only problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`nl2br()`](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) is your friend
2. This is a imaginary problem that doesn't exists, just use `nl2br()` when outputting to HTML.

Comment: Problem Solved for first question. Please help me for second question.

Comment: @Aditii: You ***don't* have** a second problem.

Comment: Yes sorry its not problem, its a question. How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

have u used nl2br() ?
i think this will solve the prob

prob 2-> $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

Comment: Please help me with second question.